# mirth connect use of executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys with Oracle

Tags: oracle, mirth, mirth-connect

I am using Mirth Connect 3.5.0.8232. I have created a persisted connection to an Oracle database and using it throughout my source and destination connectors. One of the methods Mirth provides for talking with the database is [executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.0.1/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/DatabaseConnection.html#executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys(java.lang.String)). It would be quite useful for insert statements that would return the primary keys for the inserted rows.

My question is - how do you specify WHICH columns to return? Running the provided function works, but returns ROWID in the CachedRowSet, which is not what I want.

As far as I understood, which columns to return depends on the type of the database, and every database behaves differently. I am interested in Oracle specifically.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys](http://javadocs.mirthcorp.com/connect/3.5.0/user-api/com/mirth/connect/server/userutil/DatabaseConnection.html#executeUpdateAndGetGeneratedKeys-java.lang.String-java.util.List-) method uses the [Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) flag to signal to the driver that auto-generated keys should be returned. However, from the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#CHDEGDHJ):

> If key columns are not explicitly indicated, then Oracle JDBC drivers cannot identify which columns need to be retrieved. When a column name or column index array is used, Oracle JDBC drivers can identify which columns contain auto-generated keys that you want to retrieve. However, when the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` integer flag is used, Oracle JDBC drivers cannot identify these columns. When the integer flag is used to indicate that auto-generated keys are to be returned, the `ROWID` pseudo column is returned as key. The `ROWID` can be then fetched from the ResultSet object and can be used to retrieved other columns.

So instead, try using their suggestion of passing in a column name array to `prepareStatement`:

```
var dbConn;

try {
    dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver','jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DBNAME','user','pass');

    // Create a Java String array directly
    var keyColumns = java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(java.lang.String, 1);
    keyColumns[0] = 'id';
    var ps = dbConn.getConnection().prepareStatement('INSERT INTO tablename (columnname) VALUES (?)', keyColumns);

    try {
        // Set variables here
        ps.setObject(1, 'test');
        ps.executeUpdate();

        var result = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        result.next();
        var generatedKey = result.getObject(1);

        logger.info(generatedKey);
    } finally {
        ps.close();
    }
} finally {
    if (dbConn) {
        dbConn.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, Nick - thanks for the code too - i also saw that getGeneratedKeys sometimes may throw unsupported action (or something like this) exception.